# Find the points where tangent line has a y intercept of 5. I need a step by step process.

Tags: calculus

Find the points where tangent line intersects $y$-axis at $y=5$ where
$$
f(x)=\frac {8}{(x^2 + x + 2)}
$$
I need a step by step process to help me solve this problem. I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) let the point be $(a,f(a))$
2) find $f'(a)$
3)write the equation (using the point-slope form (have you googled that?)) for the tangent line through $(a,f(a))$.
4) Find the $a$'s where it goes through $(0,5)$
Do you understand why this process works?

Comment: So the equation would be y-f(a)="derivative"(x-a), then I would plug in (0,5) for x and y?

Comment: That is right. That should give you an equation for $a$.